# regex not working in pycharm

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all matches and delete them, lets say I need delete macros defined on two lines:

```
#define something \
void single(double * state, char ch);
```

I got this regex: `#.*\n.*` , it is working on pyregex.com, and pythex.com but not in my code:

```
myFile = re.sub('#.*\n.*',"", myFile, count=0, flags=0)
```

I tried even `r"""#.*\\\n.*"""`, but none of it works

Comment: to get the backslash to appear once you use the `r`prefix: `r'#.*\n.*'` or escape the backslash without `r` prefix: `'#.*\\n.*'`

Comment: then could you show the code that did work on one of those sites?

Comment: `string="#define somenthing \
    void single(double * state, char ch);"
    string = re.sub('#.*\\\n.*',"", string, count=0, flags=0)
    print(string)`(after slash there is newline)

prints:`#define somenthing void single(double * state, char ch);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
In [78]: s = """#define something \
....: void single(double * state, char ch);
....: /*something else*/"""

In [97]: re.sub(r"#.*?\n","", s)
Out[97]: '/*something else*/'
```

Please comment if it worked or not.

Comment: What is the trailing \  in the first line?

Comment: @nocturne so, you want to delete the first two lines?

Comment: this is the thing i wanna delete:
http://pastebin.com/HVsiaS2L

it looks like there is not newline, I just want to delete that first and second line after \

Comment: @nocturne In my example the first two lines are deleted, are't they.

Comment: yes, they are deleted, give me a second to inspect it

Comment: I dont get it, when it is in string it will delete it, when it is in file it wont delete it. It must be the three quotation marks doing the trick

Comment: @nocturne I think the trailing \ is messing it up.  What is it anyway?

Comment: I should represent that the define will continue on next line

Comment: @nocturne well, why don't you just match upto `;`. leave the \ off. leaving off `;` is syntaxerror anyway.

Comment: well that is a good idea, I changed it to `#.*(\s*.*)*;` problem solved :D

Answer (score 1):

try by compiling the regex to match multiline strings:

```
myFile = re.sub(re.compile('#.*\n.*', re.MULTILINE),"", myFile, count=0, flags=0)
```

Assuming you get your string from a file called `/tmp/macro.txt`, this program matches and deletes everything:

```
import re

f = open('/tmp/macro.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
print('old content:'+content)
new_content = re.sub(re.compile('#.*\n.*', re.MULTILINE),"", '/tmp/tst.tst', count=0, flags=0)

print('new content:'+new_content)
```

Even the lines after the second one - the regex needs to be updated in order to avoid that.
The `/tmp/macros.txt` file that I used for testing, is this:

```
#define somenthing \
void single(double * state, char ch);

aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
```

If your strings is defined locally (in your python program), you said it yourself that you don't have a newline in it when you print it, so a regex looking for a newline will not match.

What would match in that case, is a string that begins with `#`, like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> str="""#define something \
... void single(double * state, char ch);"""
>>> myFile = re.sub('^#.*',"", str, count=0, flags=0)
>>> myFile
''
>>> str
'#define something void single(double * state, char ch);'
>>>
```

Comment: try and print the string you want to match and replace - are you sure you have a newline in it?

Comment: this is the thing i wanna delete: pastebin.com/HVsiaS2L it looks like there is not newline, I just want to delete that first and second line after \